# How to show www.imdb.com in iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, imdb

I want to show http://www.imdb.com in an iframe, but the below code doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="http://www.imdb.com/" width="400" height="400"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know the reason? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this is, that imdb.com is sending an "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" response header. This option prevents the browser from displaying iFrames that are not hosted on the same domain as the parent page.

See: [Mozilla Developer Network - The X-Frame-Options response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)